PostgreSQL jsonb indexing and searching for arrays and unknown keys
I am working on a PostgreSQL (version 16) database that has two tables, one with data such as id and name and such, and the other table has a jsonb column. I separated the tables because the jsonb data is heavy and was causing queries that don't need it to be slower due to reading in too many pages.
Both tables are partitioned on time (1 partition per month) and will hold a few million rows per month.
The first table looks like this:



id
name
status
timeutc




1
SN53FD
1
2024-06-28 3:05:34 PM


2
GF98LD
4
2024-06-28 3:06:23 PM


3
MP32TT
4
2024-06-28 3:07:03 PM



The second table looks like this:



id
timeutc
jdoc




1
2024-06-28 3:05:34 PM
{JSON}


2
2024-06-28 3:06:23 PM
{JSON}


3
2024-06-28 3:07:03 PM
{JSON}



The column jdoc is defined as jsonb and the json structure will look something like this:
{
    "x_data": {
        "key 1": "pass",
        "key 2": "all clear"
    },
    "y_data": {
        "key 1": "432.34",
        "key 8": "roaming"
    },
    "z_data": [{
        "key 1": "point 12",
        "key 2": "234.32",
        "key 3": "blue"
    },{
        "key 1": "point 53",
        "key 2": "50.0",
        "key 3": "green"
    },{
        "key 5": "idle",
        "key 6": "stuck",
        "key 7": "543"
    }]
}

I do not know what the names of the keys will be beforehand, "key 1" is just a placeholder, it could be anything, like "color" or "name" - but, I have no idea what it is beforehand. Also, the items in the "z_data" field can be duplicated with different values, or be different items.
All this is just to say, I really don't know what is going to be in the json data, other than the "x_data", the "y_data", and the "z_data" with the last one being an array of objects.
I need to be able to group by and filter on any one of the keys. I will be supplied with the relevant key name at runtime, but not before.
I put an index on both tables on the id and timeutc columns.
Here is an example of a query:
SELECT
    b.jdoc->'x_data'->>'key 1',
    (count (*) filter (where a.status in (1,4))) as total_count,
    (count (*) filter (where a.status in (1))) as passed_count,
    (count (*) filter (where a.status in (4))) as failed_count,
    (round(count(*) filter (where a.status in (1)) / count(*) filter (where a.status in (1,4))::numeric, 4) * 100) as ratio
FROM
    table_a AS a
    INNER JOIN table_b AS b on b.id = a.id
WHERE
    a.timeutc BETWEEN '2024-06-28T05:00:00.0000000Z' AND '2024-06-29T05:00:00.0000000Z'
    AND b.timeutc BETWEEN '2024-06-28T05:00:00.0000000Z' AND '2024-06-29T05:00:00.0000000Z'
    AND b.jdoc->'x_data' ? 'key 1'
GROUP BY 1;

Because it does a lot of counting, this is pretty slow even before joining to the second table. Then when it has to search through all the json data it becomes unusably slow. It can take up to 2 or more minutes to return. How can I index this (or restructure the query) to make it faster?

Don't just describe the table structure and indexes, include the actual DDL in the post.

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your query and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update of your question.
